# SQL Query (Display Positive and Negative value with two columns)

Tags: t-sql

I have one column table with negative and positive values and want to display positive and negative values in different columns using SQL Query.

```
Column
-10000
-17000
 16000
 25000
```

output should be like

```
A          B 
-----------------
-10000
            16000
-17000 
            25000
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a couple of `CASE` expressions.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN [Column] < 0 THEN [Column]
       END AS A,
       CASE
         WHEN [Column] >= 0 THEN [Column]
       END AS B
FROM   YourTable
```